# FCK editor renders image tag with strange slashes

Tags: php, fckeditor

I've been struggling with this for a while and I decided to ask for help. I don't understand why this is happening, when I use FCK editor to upload images and then I save the changes, the images are rendered with strange slashes. I don't know if this has to do with magic quotes (I'm using php to drive the site). Here's an example of the markup I'm talking about:

```
<img alt="\&quot;\&quot;"     src="\&quot;http://www.cesaisc.com/archivos_filemanager/image/esquema_preparatoria.jpg\&quot;"    style="\&quot;width:" 890px;="" height:="" 489px;\"="">
```

As a result, obviously the image doesn't show up in the page.
¿Has anybody had this problem? I would appreciate some orientation as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCK editor sometimes requires to use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stripslashes.php) when outputing data, since it adds them before saving data to the DB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had forgotten to make the changes you suggested due to a lot of work. When I got to it I was wondering how to modify the FCK Editor source code, thinking if I should deal with io.php, config.php, utils.php or whatever, until I realized it was my code I had to edit. Call me what you like, unless it's too offensive! Simply adding stripslashes before updating the database row made the trick.